# Generics: How to capture a wildcard?

Tags: java, generics

No, this question is not about the difference between ? and T; it is about how I turn a < ? > argument into a named < T >. 
Consider this example code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

class A<T extends Serializable> {
    <S extends Serializable> void bar(S arg) { }
    void bar2(T arg) { }
}

public class B {
    A<? extends Serializable> myA = null;    
    <T extends Serializable> void foo(T arg) {
        myA.bar(arg);
        myA.bar2(arg);
    }
}
```

My problem is the fact that the above doesn't compile; the call to bar2() gives me

```
The method bar2(capture#2-of ? extends Serializable) in the type
A<capture#2-of ? extends Serializable> is not applicable for the arguments (T)
```

I guess the "reason" for that is that myA is a *< ? extends Serializable >*; but the T in B.foo ... is well, a named T; and not the wildcard ?.

One way to "fix" this would be to make *< T extends Serializable >* a type parameter for class B ... but that basically conflicts with my other usage of that class. Meaning: I ended up writing down B and its member myA like this - exactly because I don't want to parameterize the B class. So, I started with only the bar2() method; and then added bar() later on ... but that doesn't really help either.

So - is there a way to for my class B to use A.bar2() as "intended" in my example code?

EDIT: and just to be precise - the bar() method doesn't help me; as the "S" there ... isn't compatible with the "T" that I am really using in my A class.

Comment: Create a method with a similar signature and use it to capture the wildcard.

Comment: @CKing I have to admit that I stared on my code for more than an hour by now; I guess I am turning "generics-blind" - so do you mind putting up some example code? I can't see no left or right regarding < and that > right now ...

Comment: You are right. It's not as easy as I thought it would be.

Comment: This question seems to be left unattended by you :)

Comment: It works!! Time for me to do this on all my unovted answers then :)

Comment: You are welcome. But I guess you wont find too many questions coming from my side where I forgot to accept answers. But I am going to check too ;-)

Comment: Yup. I am sure this was a one-off in your case. This seems to be a good way to capitalize on unaccounted votes ;)

Comment: @CKing I only wish I got get rid of the (totally undeserved ;-) downvotes on my questions. And woha, I actually found 4 more ones with an acceptable answer ...

Comment: 4 more. Lucky you. That's 8 points for you and 100 for the others. It's like finding some loose change in the corner of the house. Regarding the downvotes, I feel you. Sometimes they just don't make sense.

Comment: @CKing They make sense. Typically "ok" or "maybe not the greatest but still OK" questions get downvoted ... after me telling some other person "sorry, but your question is off-topic or so". Most of my "negative" rated questions came to that rating *after* such incidents; en block. Like you looking into achievements and finding: woha, 3, 4 questions block-downvoted. But of course, that is not serial downvoting, so one cant do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JBNizet already explains why this can't be done. This answer aims to explain the possible options you have (one of them being rightly pointed out by in your question but that's not the only option).

**Make B take a type parameter**

```
class B<T extends Serializable> {

    A<T> myA = null;    

    void foo(T arg) {
        myA.bar(arg);
        myA.bar2(arg);
    }
}
```

**Make B extend from A (If B passes the is-a test for A)**

```
class B extends A<String> {

    public void foo(String arg) {
        bar2(arg);
        bar(1);
    }
}
```

The difference between the two options is that in 1)  both `bar` and `bar2` need to be passed the same type where as in 2) `bar` and `bar2` can be passed different types since `bar2` is bound by the type parameter declared for `A` where as `bar` is bound by the type parameter declared for the method.

Answer (score 2):

You're in a dead end.

```
A<? extends Serializable> myA = ...;
```

So `myA` is a `A` of something unknown. It could be a `A<String>`, or a `A<Integer>` or a `A<Banana>`. You just don't know. Let's say it's a `A<Banana>`.

```
<T extends Serializable> void foo(T arg) {
```

So `foo()` accepts any serializable: String, Integer, Banana, Apple, anything. Let's say it's called with an `Integer` as argument.

```
myA.bar2(arg);
```

So, based on the assumptions above, that would call `bar2()` with an Integer as argument, although `myA` is a `A<Banana>`. That can't be accepted by the compiler: it's clearly not type-safe. `B` must be made generic.